# Stuck in heroku trying to deploy express and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So basically I am trying to deploy express and  react to heroku and i have gotten stuck in a building loop that keeps trying printing. The project works  perfectly in development mode though
[image]

For some reason it can progress further than the second step

This is the  package.json for my client

```
`{
  "name": "udendu-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "clarifai": "^2.7.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "last-fm": "^5.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-app": "^1.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-native-cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "react-player": "^1.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-responsive": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-sound": "^1.1.0",
    "react-speech-recognition": "^1.0.6",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "serve": "^6.5.6",
    "tachyons": "^4.9.1",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.6",
    "video-react": "^0.10.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "youtube-api-search": "^0.0.5",
    "ytsearch": "^1.0.4",
    "zip-array": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "concurrently \"yarn build\" \"cd server && yarn build\"",
    "clean": "concurrently \"rimraf node_modules\" \"cd server && rimraf node_modules build\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build",
    "install": "(yarn) && (cd server && yarn)",
    "start": "concurrently \"PORT=3000 yarn start\" \"cd server && PORT=5000 yarn start\"",
    "start:prod": "cd server && yarn start:prod"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
`
```

This is the package.json for my server

```
  "name": "website_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this is where te server for my app resides",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "udendu abasili",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel . --ignore node_modules,build --out-dir build",
    "start": "nodemon -r babel-register server.js",
    "start:prod": "node build/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.16",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: lol the picture didnt upload the first time. it is there now